# How can I get the values at every nth hour from a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to get values at every nth hour from a Pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame uses a DateTime column as index like this:

```
                                                       Value A             Value B               Value C
timestamp
2021-03-29 23:58:59.443000+00:00                           0.7                 0.2                   0.0
2021-03-29 23:58:59.458000+00:00                           0.0                 0.1                   0.1
2021-03-29 23:58:59.474000+00:00                           0.3                 0.0                   0.2
2021-03-29 23:59:59.446000+00:00                           0.2                 0.0                   0.0
2021-03-29 23:59:59.461000+00:00                           0.0                 0.0                   0.5
```

Now I would like to extract the values at every nth hour. What is the best way to do this? The only way I can think of right now is generate a list with the dates at which the values should be extracted then loop through this list find the date in the DataFrame with the smallest difference and get the values at that date. But this feels like rather bad practice.

Comment: Possibly something like: `df.index.dt.hour.isin([1, 3, 5, 7])` kind of thing?

Comment: Looks very promising, will try it immediately!

Comment: Does this work with data that spans over more than one day though?

Comment: Another suggestion, try `df.asfreq` maybe `df.asfreq("nH")`  or resample `df.resample("nH").first()` replace n with a number or even [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html#:~:text=Select%20values%20between%20particular%20times,not%20between%20the%20two%20times.) depending on what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `asof` merge. This will merge the entire row for the closest time in your DataFrame to the hourly cadence. You can change the direction to be closest in the future or past instead of either direction.

```
import pandas as pd

# Series of hours that span the range of the Index
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(df.index.min().floor('H'), df.index.max().ceil('H'), freq='H'),
              name='times')

pd.merge_asof(s, df.reset_index(), left_on='times', right_on='timestamp', direction='nearest')
```

---

```
                      times                        timestamp  ValueA  ValueB  ValueC
0 2021-03-29 23:00:00+00:00 2021-03-29 23:58:59.443000+00:00     0.7     0.2     0.0
1 2021-03-30 00:00:00+00:00 2021-03-29 23:59:59.461000+00:00     0.0     0.0     0.5
```

Comment: Would this work for data that spans over more than one day?

Comment: Depends what you want. If you want the closest value to 2010-01-01 01:00:00 then yes this will work. But if you want the closest time to the hour 01:00:00 independent of the date, then you can still use it but you'll need to turn your times into timestamps and merge that way, though the circularity of 24 == 0 needs to be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .loc functionality by filtering using a conditional throughout your dataframe based on you column/index you selected.

```
nth_df = df.loc[df.index.dt.hour.isin([9])]
```

with it as a column

```
nth_df = df.loc[df['timestamp'].dt.hour.isin([9])]
```

both will result in getting rows that are across multiple days. You can add more conditionals with the & like so:

```
nth_df = df.loc[df.index.dt.hour.isin([9]) & df.index.dt.minute.isin([30])]
```